# Minimum speed for stable motorbike ride along a straight line on flat ground

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

What is the critical minimum angular speed of wheels or connected linear speed of motorbike along a straight line to avoid falling and remain stable on a motorbike in terms of moment of inertia $I$  of each of the two  wheels of mass $m$, mass of rider plus bike frame $M$, height of their center of gravity $h?$

Is there a differential equation of motion for stability? Or do we just equate rotational (PE) and linear kinetic energies (KE) ?

EDIT

Hypothetically its handlebar is welded to the frame and  cannot rotate, only open loop dynamics required for track holding. Thanks.

Comment: Many people do fine balancing without moving...

Comment: Minimum speed depends on the rider's skill.  There is no absolute minimum.  Google for "track stand."

Comment: Delightfully messy problem.  There will be coupled ODEs for the lean of the bike and the turn of the handlebars.  There will also be a gyroscopic damping effect.  Don't expect a quick answer.

Comment: Edited it. I want the simplest calculation with uniform motion of a motorbike along a straight line.

Comment: Track standing requires closed loop corrections to be stable. I think it is fairly clear the OP is talking about open loop stability.

Comment: Yes,  starting with basic open loop dynamics we can  extend it to closed loops. Hypothetically its handlebar is welded to the frame and  cannot rotate.

Comment: You seem to be asking for a calculation which you have not attempted to do yourself. Do you have a conceptual difficulty?

Comment: I had the following query in mind. For time being ignore  where the initial boost came from, there is a bike travelling at a sufficiently high speed  vertically upright  and also assuming that  it gradually decelerates.. at what speed does it  tip over and fall off ?

Answer (score 2):

Here’s my concise answer, but see Wikipedia for a longer article with figures:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_and_motorcycle_dynamics

Let $\theta$ denote the lean of the bike, $\varphi$ the turn of the handlebars, $\alpha \approx 73{}^\circ$ the “head angle” formed by the axis of the steering column to the ground, $x\approx$ 107 cm the wheelbase, $M\approx$ 70+10 kg the mass of the rider plus bike, $h\approx$ 110 cm the altitude of the CM, $m\approx$ 2 kg  the mass of the front wheel, and $r\approx$ 35 cm its radius.  The relevant moments of inertia will be ${{I}_{\omega }}=m{{r}^{2}}$, ${{I}_{\theta }}=M{{h}^{2}}$, and ${{I}_{\varphi }}=???$ for the steering assembly plus wheel.

The key issue is whether centrifugal forces are sufficient to keep the bike from tipping over to the side, but this will depend on the curvature of the trajectory, which depends on the turn of the handlebars and the wheelbase.  Gyroscopic torques are less important.

Gyroscopic effects aside, the tipping torques are 
$${{I}_{\theta }}\ddot{\theta }=HMg\sin (\theta )-HM\tfrac{{{v}^{2}}}{x}\cos (\theta )\sin (\alpha )\sin (\varphi )$$

The front struts are curved to make the wheel self-righting when in contact with the ground, with some natural frequency $\Omega $.  Its equilibrium turn angle exceeds the bike’s lean angle: $$\tan ({{\varphi }_{0}})/\tan (\theta )=\sec (\alpha )$$
Linearizing, we get $$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
   {\ddot{\theta }}  \\
   {\ddot{\varphi }}  \\
\end{matrix} \right]=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   +g/h & -{{v}^{2}}/hx  \\
   +{{\Omega }^{2}}\sec (\alpha ) & -{{\Omega }^{2}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right]\ \left[ \begin{matrix}
   \theta   \\
   \varphi   \\
\end{matrix} \right] $$

We can infer the signs of the eigenvalues from the determinant without knowing the value of ${{I}_{\varphi }}$ or $\Omega$, and we may conclude that the coupled system will be unstable unless ${{v}^{2}}>gx\cos (\alpha )$, so $v>$ 1.75 m/s or 6.3 km/h.  It is also essential that ${{\Omega }^{2}}>g/h$, which depends on having sufficient “rake” of the forks, weight on the front wheel, and low ${{I}_{\varphi }}$.

Gyroscopic torques contribute small correction terms proportional to the rates of change of steering, lean, and direction:
$$\begin{align}
  & {{I}_{\theta }}\ddot{\theta }=\ldots +{{I}_{\omega }}\tfrac{v}{r}[\dot{\varphi }\sin (\alpha )+\tfrac{v}{x}\varphi ] \\ 
 & {{I}_{\varphi }}\ddot{\varphi }=\ldots -{{I}_{\omega }}\tfrac{v}{r}[\dot{\theta }\cos (\alpha )] \\ 
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is way too complicated for me. I like to look at only the basics.

Answer (score 2):

There is a misconception that gyroscopic motion is the main contributor to the vertical stability of a bicycle-like vehicle.  In fact, the stability is largely a result of the geometry of the front wheel and steering mechanism, and the way that, as the bike tilts, the wheel will turn toward the direction of the tilt and "correct" it.

It is easily possible to design a bike (or motorbike) that is inherently unstable and can only be balanced by a gymnast.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_and_motorcycle_dynamics#Balance):

> If the steering of a bike is locked, it becomes virtually impossible
>   to balance while riding. On the other hand, if the gyroscopic effect
>   of rotating bike wheels is cancelled by adding counter-rotating
>   wheels, it is still easy to balance while riding.[5][6] One other way
>   that a bike can be balanced, with or without locked steering, is by
>   applying appropriate torques between the bike and rider similar to the
>   way a gymnast can swing up from hanging straight down on uneven
>   parallel bars, a person can start swinging on a swing from rest by
>   pumping their legs, or a double inverted pendulum can be controlled
>   with an actuator only at the elbow.[33]

Comment: I agree. But can you give a citation for the sentence "In fact, the stability is largely a result of the geometry...."; this sounds interesting and I am having trouble visualizing it. I hadn't realized there were factors, other than the rider's closed loop control of the system balance - illustrated  by the wheelless snow bike (the unmotorized ones).